# Return XML from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have to return XML from SQL Server Stored Proc in the below format:

```
<Customer1>
 <Policy1></Policy1>
 <Policy2></Policy2>
</Customer1>
<Customer2>
 <Policy1></Policy1>
 <Policy2></Policy2>
 <Policy3></Policy3>`
<Customer2>
.......
```

The problem is that my Query is creating `<Customer>` nodes for each row.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Please show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see numbered names (*Policy1, Policy2...* or *Customer1, Customer2*) you can be sure, that there is bad design!

In your case it seems, that **you want to use the column value as element name**. That is something you **really should not do**!

Assuming there is a customer table with ID and Name and a policy table with ID, CustomerID and Number it might look like this:

```
DECLARE @customer TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @customer VALUES(1,'cust 1'),(2,'cust 2'),(3,'cust 3');

DECLARE @policy TABLE(ID INT,CustomerID INT,Number VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @policy VALUES
 (1,1,'p1 for c1'),(2,1,'p2 for c1')
,(3,2,'p1 for c2'),(4,2,'p2 for c2'),(5,2,'p3 for c2')
--no policy for c3

SELECT ID AS [@id]
      ,Name AS [@name]
      ,(
        SELECT ID AS [@id]
              ,Number AS [@number] 
        FROM @policy AS p
        WHERE p.CustomerID=c.ID
        FOR XML PATH('policy'),ROOT('policies'),TYPE
       )
FROM @customer AS c
FOR XML PATH('Customer')
```

The result

```
<Customer id="1" name="cust 1">
    <policies>
        <policy id="1" number="p1 for c1" />
        <policy id="2" number="p2 for c1" />
    </policies>
</Customer>
<Customer id="2" name="cust 2">
    <policies>
        <policy id="3" number="p1 for c2" />    
        <policy id="4" number="p2 for c2" />
        <policy id="5" number="p3 for c2" />
    </policies>
</Customer>
<Customer id="3" name="cust 3" />
```

### Hint

You might let the `,ROOT('policies')` away (not recommended)